# Creating a dynamic graphic in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gdi+

I am busy creating a control in asp.net. The control consists of some text and an image. The image will be used to display a graph. The control gets the data for the graph by reading it from a database. It seems I have two options to display the graph in the image box. First, I can create a jpg from the data and save the file on the server. I can then load this file into the image box. I think this would cause a problem if various users try to access the site at the same time, so I don't think it is a good option. The other options is to create a file called output, that outputs the graph like this: `objBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif)`

I can then display the image like this in my control: `Image1.ImageUrl = "output.aspx"`

The problem that I am facing is how do I get the data from my control to the output page? As far as I know it is too much data to pass as a parameter. If there is another better method of doing it, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write the image content to the response of output.aspx. Something like this (taken from one of my existing GetImage pages:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strFilename As String

        strFilename = Request.QueryString("filename")

        Dim strPath As String = AppSettings("ProxyImageSavePath") & strFilename

        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

        If Not IO.File.Exists(strPath) Then
            'erm
            Response.Write("file not found")
        Else
            Response.WriteFile(strPath)
        End If

        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

Edit: I've just realised this may not be the solution you're looking for; Your webserver should be able to cache this though.

Answer (score 0):

You need handlers. See in this article, [Protecting Your Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx#httphandl_topic4), section "Creating the ImageHandler HTTP Handler", you'll find the code how to write the handler, so it outputs an image. You don't need all, it's only an example.

You also need to register the handler in the web.config.

To reference it Image1.ImageUrl = "handler.ashx?graphdata=xxxx". Use QueryString to get the data source to generate the graph.

Comment: Thanks, it got me on the right track. So, my data is stored in a certain table in a database. Should I send the index of the data in the database as well as the table name and then read it from there? Something like: Image1.ImageUrl = "handler.ashx?table=sales&id=10". Or are there better ways of doing it.

Comment: Welcome. This is a good way. I would opt instead of table=sales for the construction type=s (just for security reasons) and based on this you will decide which query to use.